# I am getting a problem for showing the actual info of existing employee when trying to edit

Tags: .net

I am building my first Angular and .NET application. I am currently facing the following problem:
When I am trying to "View" the Employee information, the information doesn't show up.

This is my code:

**employee service**

```
getEmployee(id: string): Observable<Employee> {
    return this.http.get<Employee>(this.baseApiUrl + '/api/employees' + id)
  }
```

**edit-employee-component.ts**

```
import { EmployeesService } from './../../../services/employees.service';
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
import { Employee } from 'src/app/models/employee.model';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-edit-employee',
  templateUrl: './edit-employee.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./edit-employee.component.css']
})
export class EditEmployeeComponent implements OnInit {

  employeeDetails: Employee = {
    id: '',
    name: "",
    email: "",
    phone: 0,
    salary: 0,
    department: ""
    
  }

  constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute, private employeeService: EmployeesService) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.route.paramMap.subscribe({
      next: (params) => {
        const id = params.get('id');

        if(id) {
          //call api
          this.employeeService.getEmployee(id)
          .subscribe({
            next: (response) => {
              this.employeeDetails = response;
            }
          });
        }
      }
    })
  }

}
```

**edit-employee-component.html**

```
<div class="container my-5">
    <h1 class="mb-3">Edit Employee</h1>


    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-6">
            <form #form="ngForm">
                <div class="mb-3">
                    <label for="id" class="form-label">If</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="if" readonly
                    name = "if" [(ngModel)]="employeeDetails.id">
                  </div>
                <div class="mb-3">
                  <label for="name" class="form-label">Name</label>
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" 
                  name = "name" [(ngModel)]="employeeDetails.name">
                </div>
                <div class="mb-3">
                    <label for="email" class="form-label">Email</label>
                    <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email"
                    name = "email" [(ngModel)]="employeeDetails.email">
                  </div>
                  <div class="mb-3">
                    <label for="phone" class="form-label">Phone</label>
                    <input type="number" class="form-control" id="phone"
                    name ="phone" [(ngModel)]="employeeDetails.phone">
                  </div>
                  <div class="mb-3">
                    <label for="salary" class="form-label">Salary</label>
                    <input type="number" class="form-control" id="salary"
                    name ="salary" [(ngModel)]="employeeDetails.salary">
                  </div>
                  <div class="mb-3">
                    <label for="department" class="form-label">Department</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="department"
                    name = "department" [(ngModel)]="employeeDetails.department">
                  </div>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Save</button>
              </form>
        </div>
    </div>
    
</div>
```

**And finally, this is the Controller method:**

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("{id:Guid}")]
public async Task<IActionResult> GetEmployee([FromRoute] Guid id)
{
    var employee = 
        await _fullStackDbContext.Employees.FirstOrDefaultAsync(x => x.Id == id);
    if (employee == null)
    {
        return NotFound();
    }
    return Ok(employee);
}
```

I would be very glad if someone helps me. Thanks very much in advance!

Comment: 404 Not found, mean the url is unable to found from API. If you read the error message from browser console in detail, you are missing '/' between '/api/employees' and the Guid. It should be `this.baseApiUrl + '/api/employees/' + id`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is that your Api is returning `404` because the construction is incorrect.

```
return this.http.get<Employee>(this.baseApiUrl + '**/api/employees**' + id)
```

Add a slash after 'employees' like below:

```
return this.http.get<Employee>(this.baseApiUrl + '/api/employees/' + id)
```

This is also evident in the screenshots you posted.